# Write Hive query for below problem to print the ID value if Id is 1 then print Id 1 time, If Id value is 2 then print Id 2 times so on

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

Write Hive query for below problem to print the ID value if Id is 1 then print Id 1 time, If Id value is 2 then print Id 2 times so on

```
Input Table

Id
---

1
2
3
4

Output
-------

Id
--
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `space(id-1)` to get string of spaces with length = id-1, split string and use [lateral view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) + `explode` to generate rows.

Demo:

```
with your_table as (
select stack (4,
1,
2,
3,
4) as id
)

select t.id
  from your_table t
       lateral view outer explode(split(space(id-1),' ')) e
```

Result:

```
t.id
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

More explanation:

`split(space(id-1),' ')` - this produces array of id-1 spaces

`explode()` - is a table generation function, generates table from array

`lateral view outer` works like a left join of main table with table generated by explode. For each row it joins with each row of explode() and in such way producing duplicates for each row.

Comment: thank for the answer. Can you please give more explanation on that.

Comment: @user13748181 Added more explanation and documentation link